# Handlebars template not rendered in Express

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

I am trying to pass javascript objects to a handlebars template. However, I am getting the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined`. However, I have express-handlebars installed and the handlebars templates are working fine on pages where I pass in data via a route. Here is my template:

```
<body>
    <div id="render_here">
        first placeholder
    </div>

    <div id="render_here_again">
        second placeholder
    <div>

    <script id="first-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div>
            <h1 style="color:green">{{title}}</h1>
            <h2 style="color:red">{{body}}</h2>
        </div>
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/templating.js"></script> 
</body>
```

And here's my .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var source = $('#first-template').html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

    var context = {
        title: "All about handlebars",
        body: "body body body"
    };

    var el_html = template(context);
    $("#render_here").html(el_html)
    $('#render_here_again').html(el_html)
});
```

And I have the express-handlebars package installed. Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: are you calling Handlebars.compile on client side (on the browser, not from node and express)? If so, you should include handlebars library inside your template as well

Comment: gotcha, i'm calling Handlebars.compile on the client side.